# Download table in php generated from data in sql

Tags: javascript, php, datatables

I apologize in advance if what I'm going to say sounds dumb. If we have a table generated in a php file, getting its data from a SQL database and the table itself is displayed thanks to an index pages, If I want to download the data from this table, where do I put the following code:

```js
< script type = 'text/javascript' >
  $(function() {
    $('#resultTable').DataTable({
      dom: 'Bfrtip',
      buttons: [
        'copy', 'csv', 'excel'
      ]
    });
  }) <
  /script>";
```

I know that we shouldn't mix js and php but here I just need to know, do I put this code snipet in the php code that generates the table or in the index page that displays the table and other stuff? I got the downloa and all that working on a sample table but nothing seems to work here. Is it impossible to use datatables in this case? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case that it is datatables, that code either should go in an external JS file

scripts.js for example:

```
$(function() {
    $('#resultTable').DataTable({
      dom: 'Bfrtip',
      buttons: [
        'copy', 'csv', 'excel'
      ]
    });
  })
```

Then be included in your page that contains #resultTable

OR

In the top of the file that controls #resultTable

I personally prefer to separate as much as possible.

Comment: I'm kina of a noob so I'm not sure how to declare the scripts.js. Ist it like: echo '<script src="some/directory/scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>';  ?

Comment: Depends on your setup. Edit your question to show all your code and I'll just edit my answer and show you

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice your reply. I finally figured it out. Again sorry for not responding.